# Programatically add/publish a record to the workspace/libraries in salsforce using apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have created a custom visualforce page.
Here in the controller class i allow the user to create folders.

I want when user clicks OK (a custom button) then the new folder is published as a record in the workspace but i cannot find how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the code you added didn't come through in your question, can you repost?

Comment: i juzz want to know how to publish a record to a workspace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i achieved a way to publish a record to **shared workspace:**

```
        ContentVersion doc = new ContentVersion();
        string before = 'Testing base 64 encode'; 
        Blob beforeblob = Blob.valueOf(before);
        doc.Title = title;
        doc.PathOnClient = 'xyz';
        doc.VersionData = beforeblob;
        insert doc;

        doc = [select ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where id = :doc.id];
        ContentWorkspace shareWorkspace = [select id from ContentWorkspace 
                  where name = :workspaceName limit 1];

        ContentWorkspaceDoc docLink = new ContentWorkspaceDoc();
        docLink.ContentDocumentId = doc.ContentDocumentId;
        docLink.ContentWorkspaceId = shareWorkspace.id;
        insert docLink;
```

Publish Record to **Personal Workspace:**

```
        ContentVersion doc = new ContentVersion();
        string before = 'Testing base 64 encode'; 
        Blob beforeblob = Blob.valueOf(before);
        doc.Title = title;
        doc.PathOnClient = title;
        doc.VersionData = beforeblob;
        **doc.FirstPublishLocationID = UserInfo.getUserId();**
        insert doc;
```

I have created a blob from String but i need to create a blob that can show a table with all the info that i want to display like size & author name.

Thanks Paul for the idea.
May be someone can help me in creating blob of my choice.

:)

Answer (score 2):

Swati

You need to create the Folder and then after inserting the Folder create a ContentWorkspaceDoc record linking the two. You can find the api reference to the object [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspacedoc.htm). This should then allow you to setup the linking you require.

Paul

Comment: Thank u Paul but can u provide me a sample code which i can follow as i have seen this link before but couldnt implement it as per my needs.

Comment: What do u mean by this : "after inserting the Folder create a ContentWorkspaceDoc record linking the two" -- where to insert the folder

Comment: Paul i can publish record to shared workspace but cant publish it to personal workspace

Comment: Look here for a Java example and then see how it does this. http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/publishing-documents-into-a-salesforce-crm-content-personal-workspace